# Where is the output directory specified in my xUnit csproj file?

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild, xunit

I am struggling to understand how Visual Studio compiles and organizes the output assemblies of my project.

I have downloaded and installed the latest Visual Studio, and ticked all the boxes to use xUnit and develop in C#.

I have used Visual Studio's UI menus to create a new project and picked the xUnit template. The files generated are few, there is a single unit test, and when I press compile, the program compiles. Everything is good so far.

However, for reasons too long to detail here, I'd like to segregate the .dll files corresponding to my test cases (all one of them for now) from the many .dll files that belong to the xUnit dependencies, specifically, I'd really like xunit.runner.visualstudio.testadapter.dll to go somewhere else. For now, everything is in the same output folder when I build.

I have looked at my TestProject1.csproj file to see if the output of the build is specified and if I can change anything, but the file is awfully laconic:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <IsTestProject>true</IsTestProject>
    <BaseOutputPath>bin\</BaseOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>obj\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.2.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I can see that the output paths are specified and the dependencies as well, but I see no instructions on how to build the project, although while reading extensively through Microsoft documentation, I was expecting to find a whole section about Targets and invocation of CSC with all sorts of parameters specifying the source files, and hopefully also, where all the outputs of the build process go... but I don't see any of that here.

Is it all implicit due to the use of the SDK?

How can I achieve my goal?

I have spent a good hour looking at similar answers, but I think my current knowledge of how this all works is too limited to synthesize an answer to my current problem from other solutions similar looking problems I could find. A pointer to a good starting point for learning about .csproj files would be appreciated, the Microsoft documentation has been so far very hard to navigate.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you will create a solution (.sln) file. The solution file will define a set of projects. You may be working on a "Foo" library and in your solution, you will have a `Foo` project (Foo.csproj) which is the library itself and a `Foo_Tests` project (Foo_Tests.csproj) which is the set of unit tests for `Foo`.

A project produces an assembly (either .exe or .dll). The name of the assembly is available in the `$(TargetName)` property. The `$(TargetFileName)` property is the `$(TargetName)` + the file extension. `$(TargetFileName)` will be `Foo.dll` and `Foo_Tests.dll` for Foo.csproj and Foo_Tests.csproj, respectively.

The `Foo_Tests` project will have a `ProjectReference` to `Foo` because that is the Subject Under Test (SUT). `Foo_Tests.dll` will have a dependency on `Foo.dll`.

Generally, `ProjectReference`s and `PackageReference`s will be resolved and the dependencies will be copied to the project's output folder. Generally, the files needed to load and execute `$(TargetFileName)` are collected in the output folder. The files can be moved around but if the dependencies are no longer in the search path the debugger and the Test Explorer won't be able to load or execute the assembly.

The `SDK` attribute on the `Project` element causes a set of files to be imported into the project that provide the basic build functionality. But you can use the `-preprocess` switch to get a file that has all the imports performed.

Running the unit tests can be configured and/or customized with a .runsettings file.

Docs:

- [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022)
- [MSBuild and .NET project SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview)
- [MSBuild properties that are common but for some reason are only in the C++ docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-170#list-of-common-macros)
- [Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Hello ! 
Thank you very much for you answer, it does point me in the right direction, especially the -preprocess switch idea which I hope I can leverage since I am building with Visual Studio I am not sure I can just use it but I can just try to compile my project with MSbuild and see if your idea just works. 
You mentioned that if the files are moved the test explorer might not be able to execute the test assembly: is it possible to change the search path to remedy this ?
Thank you for your swift reply !

Comment: Build in Visual Studio is equivalent to `msbuild -t:build`. You will need to run the `-preprocess` at the command line and that's okay.

Comment: You may want to create a .runsettings file for your unit tests. See [Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Thank you ! I have successfully used the preprocess flag and gotten the detailed csproj file but now it's quite overwhelming ! I need some more time to check out your links and do some learning/reading on my own before getting back to you on whether I've succeeded. Thanks again !